# How to extract body attribute by another attribute REST-ASSURED JAVA

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I have following response after GET request :

```
[
    {
        "id": 81,
        "userId": null,
        "title": "test1",
        "status": "TODO"
    },
    {
        "id": 564,
        "userId": null,
        "title": "test2",
        "status": "TODO"
    },
    {
        "id": 660,
        "userId": null,
        "title": "test3",
        "status": "TODO"
    }
]
```

What is the best way to get object `ID` by `title` attribute?

For example I need to find `ID` of "test3".

I have 100 + objects in response and it's hard to find it manually.

Comment: Unmarshal the json to a list of objects with those four properties, let's call the resulting list `response`, then do something like `response.stream().filter(x -> "test3".equals(x.getTitle())).findFirst().map(x -> x.getId()).orElse(null);`

Comment: JSONPath can also be used to filter out the records. In your case it would be something like ``$.[?(@.title=="test3")].id``. You can try this on online evaluator http://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

Beside 2 solutions that others commented, I add another one.

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

Response res = ...;
int id = JsonPath.from(res.asString()).get("find {it.title == 'test3'}.id");
```